# jquery dialog conversion

Tags: jquery, html, flash, jquery-dialog

I use a combination of html/php and javascript to open a new browser window that launches a flash app.  This works fine, but most users these days don't expect window popups and often forget to allow the popups.  So I thought a good solution might be using Jquery's dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default.

I'm looking for some guidance here on how to implement this with jquery dialog as this flash app needs many things passed into it.  Hence the round about way of doing this.

I first create a button in html with a bunch of things pulled out of a DB:

```
<button id="monitor" onClick='startmonitor("<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>","<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>","<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>","<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>")'>Monitor</button>
```

Then I create a form in javascript with the passed parameters from the button:

```
 function startmonitor(to, camerahash, cameraname, cameraflashquality)
 {
    var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.method = "post";
    myForm.action = to;

    var myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.name="video";
    myInput.value="Monitor";
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);

    myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.name="camera_hash";
    myInput.value=camerahash;
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);

    myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.name="camera_name";
    myInput.value=cameraname;
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);

    myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.name="camera_quality_flash";
    myInput.value=cameraflashquality;
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);

    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    myForm.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(myForm);
 }
```

And finally process this in php further and call javascript to launch flash app:

```
if (isset($_POST['video'])) {
    //get user hash for monitor app
    $query_user_hash = "SELECT id_hash FROM #__users WHERE user_id=".$user->id;
    $db->setQuery($query_user_hash);
    $id_hash = $db->loadResult();

    $camera_hash = check_input($_POST['camera_hash']);
    $camera_name = check_input($_POST['camera_name']);
    $camera_quality_flash = check_input($_POST['camera_quality_flash']);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("flashapp/app.php?user='.$id_hash.'&camera='.$camera_hash.'&name='.$camera_name.'&quality='.$camera_quality_flash.'", "Flash_monitor", "location=0,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=360,height=405")
    </script>';
}
```

Not even sure where to start from here.  Do I try to use jquery dialog where I do the `window.open`? In which case I'm not sure how I pass the same parameters?  Or is there a better way to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the dynamic creation of a form and posting back to the server may be unnecessary. All seems it you are really doing is looking up the user's id_hash. If you had that available on the main page you would not need the extra server side call. Then you could do something like this:

```
<button id="monitor" onclick="startMonitor('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>', '<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>');">Monitor</button>
```

and

```
var startMonitor = function(cameraHash, cameraName) {
    var url = ['flashapp/app.php?user=<?php echo $user_id_hash; ?>', 'camera=' + cameraHash, 'name=' + cameraName, 'quality=<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>'].join('&');
    $('<div></div>').load(url, function() {
        $(this).dialog();
    });
};
```

Comment: Your right I only need the user id_hash and that is easy to get.  No idea why I went down this route.  This seems very elegant.  However does fail due the the quoting (which you can see in the Monitor button).  Are you sure about this way to quote? I've never seen this way before. I'll keep playing with this.

Comment: The code above should work.  
@NateBolam: a few more suggestions: the 2nd `<div>` in the jQuery selector should be `</div>` (missing slash) and add a `;` to the end of each php-echo.  
@TomPepernic: Can you show us the result from the `flashapp/app.php`-request?

Comment: The problem with the space in cameraName could be solved with `... + encodeURIComponent(cameraName), ...`.

Comment: Yes, that worked great, but still have other issues here like camera_quality_flash and the jquery error.  Any other suggestions?  I think I'm close...

Comment: I've got everything resolved in the GET so it all looks good, I'm just left with this: `missing ; before statement` jquery.js line 612. Not sure where to go from here.  I'm using jquery 1.7.1 and jquery ui 1.8.16

Comment: Ack, way too much trial and error but something about the join caused problems.  I removed that and added missing concatenation and voila...well sort of.  I think it is showing as a close link appears on the screen, that is the next question...